# MvvmCross - Stuck in splash screen

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I'm developping a small aplication with MvvmCross and Xamarin.Forms.
I built the project following the tutorial from the MvvmCross website; the thing is that when I try to add a splash screen (on the android project) to appear while the main viewmodel is loading it gets stuck on it...
I attach you my Start.cs (which will be equal to a MainActivity file) the setup and the SplashScreen config:

```
    [Activity(
    Label = "@string/app_name",
    Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
    MainLauncher = false,
    LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask,
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class Start : MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<Setup, App, FormsApp>
{
    //LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask
    //MvxFormsAppCompatActivity<MvxFormsAndroidSetup<App, FormsApp>, App, FormsApp>
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

    }
}
```

Setup:

```
    public class Setup : MvxFormsAndroidSetup<App, FormsApp>
{
}
```

SplashScreen:

```
    [Activity(
    Label = "Template", 
    MainLauncher = true, 
    NoHistory = true,
    Theme = "@style/AppTheme",
    Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class SplashScreen : MvxSplashScreenActivity
{
    public SplashScreen()
        :base(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen)
    {
    }
    protected override void RunAppStart(Bundle bundle)
    {
        StartActivity(typeof(Start));
        base.RunAppStart(bundle);
    }
}
```

Does anybody knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try putting Finish(); after base.RunAppStart(bundle); ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What version of MvvmCross you're using?

Generally speaking, try to follow what's in the the Playground samples. For the Xamarin.Forms Droid you should have a look at [Playground.Forms.Droid](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Droid) - I would suggest downloading MvvmCross sources (use develop branch) on your machine and trying to run this sample.

I suspect that the problem lies in the part where you're inheriting from `MvxSplashScreenActivity`. Try to inherit from the generic version of that class e.g. `MvxFormsSplashScreenActivity<Setup, Core.App, FormsApp>`. Have a look at how the [splash screen class](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/develop/Projects/Playground/Playground.Forms.Droid/SplashScreen.cs) looks like in the Playground sample

If that doesn't help, then literally check how your app is different from the Playground sample app and fill the missing parts

Comment: I'm suing mvvmcross 6.2.0. I will try your recomendation following the sample that you shown me.

Comment: It seems that the issue was on the RunAppStart, using RunAppStartAsync fix the issue. Thanks for your help!